# Hyperleder Composer docker container occupying space

Tags: docker, hyperledger-composer

I had started `Hyperledger-composer` from `fabric-dev-server`, So all images running as regular.

Now after two weeks I had seen that my HDD space is occupied by docker container.

So, Here are some screenshots of my hdd space:

**Day-1**

[image]

**Day-2**

[image]

In 2 days, the hdd available size become `9.8G` to `9.3G`.

So, How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the docker container of `peer0` is generating too many logs, so if you run that container continuously, it will generate more logs when you access the fabric network.

you can check the file size of the log for particular docker container:

1. Find container id of `peer0`.
2. Goto directory `/var/lib/docker/containers/container_id/`.
3. There should be a file named as `container_id-json.log`.

So in my case:

My fabric was running from 2 weeks, and the logs file is at (example):

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/a50ea6b441ee327587a73e2a0efc766ff897bed2e187575fd69ff902b56a5830/a50ea6b441ee327587a73e2a0efc766ff897bed2e187575fd69ff902b56a5830-json.log
```

I had check the size of that file, it was near `6.5GB`.

**Solution (Temporary):**

Run below command, which will delete data of that file (example):

```
> var/lib/docker/containers/a50ea6b441ee327587a73e2a0efc766ff897bed2e187575fd69ff902b56a5830/a50ea6b441ee327587a73e2a0efc766ff897bed2e187575fd69ff902b56a5830-json.log
```

**Solution (Permanent):**

What you can do this just make a script that run everyday and remove data from that log file.

You can use `crontab`, which give you ability to run script on specific time,day etc.